# Visual Studio Database Unit Tests - Checksum

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am trying to use the Database unit tests in Visual Studio 2010.  I created a test where I am using checksum to validate the result set in one of my tables.  If I tested on the data it works fine until I delete the rows and reload the same data.  I am not including any field that could change (identities, derived dates, etc) which would obviously change the checksum output.

Is there something I need to do so I can implement this? It would be really nice ot have it validate the 20+ rows in the table using the checksum.

OS: windows 7 64bit

Comment: I think you'll have to add the table definition(s) (as `CREATE TABLE` preferably) and your `CHECKSUM` code.

Comment: I would not use checksum at all, because you don't know what went wrong if your checksum does not match. Is there one value wrong, are your rows in wrong order, or is one row missing? Checksum does not answer such questions. As such, it is not very useful.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov - `CHECKSUM` works against a single row, so row order would not affect it. `CHECKSUM_AGG` works against multiple rows, but is *documented* to not be affected by row order.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever my point is different: when checksum is not as expected, we still have to figure out whether all the columns in a row are totally wrong or we have 1.59997 instead of 1.6 in one column and all others match. As such, we have to waste time determining what exactly went wrong. So typically checksum approach is just not good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got around this....instead of using the Checksum test type I used scalar and rolled my own checksum logic on my rows.

- In the query that is used for the validation I added a checksum column for the row where I am doing a checksum on all of the columns I want to validate.
- I then sum up these checksums.

Now when I run the test and reload the data it is correctly evaluating the data.  If anyone has another option for utilizng the out of the box checksum I would appreciate it.

Comment: We would, again, need to see *some* actual code. `CHECKSUM` does work, generally, it's not like it includes some hidden information about table rows, so we've not been given enough information to answer your question, as yet.

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever I will try to add some to the question so you can see where I am maybe going wrong